# Pytorch: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Whatever I do, I encounter this error, what should I do?

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4ea723df6eea> in __init__(self, steps, multiplier, prev_prev_C, prev_C, curr_C, reduction, prev_reduction)
     36 
     37     self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
-->  38     for i in range(steps):
     39         for j in range(2+i):
     40             stride = 2 if reduction and j < 2 else 1
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

```
class SearchCell(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, steps, multiplier, prev_prev_C, prev_C, curr_C, reduction, prev_reduction):
    super(SearchCell, self).__init__()
    self.steps = steps
    self.multiplier = multiplier
    self.reduction = reduction
  
    if prev_reduction:
      self.prep0 = FactorizedReduce(prev_prev_C,curr_C, affine=False)
    else:
      self.prep0 = ReLUConvBN(prev_prev_C, curr_C, 1, 1, 0, affine=False)
    self.prep1 = ReLUConvBN(prev_C, curr_C, 1, 1, 0, affine=False)

    self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
    for i in range(steps):
        for j in range(2+i):
            stride = 2 if reduction and j < 2 else 1
            op = MixedOp(curr_C, stride)
            self.layers.append(op)

  def forward(self, s0, s1, weights):
    s0 = self.prep0(s0)
    s1 = self.prep1(s1)
    states = [s0, s1]
    offset = 0
    for i in range(self.steps):
      s = sum([self.layers[offset + j](h, weights[offset + j]) for j, h in enumerate(states)])
      offset += len(states)
      states.append(s)

    return torch.cat(states[-self.multiplier:], dim=1)
```

Comment: you passed a string for steps, instead of an integer.

Comment: please review [mre]

Comment: **identical question**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73597607/pytorch-typeerror-str-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer

Answer (score 0):

according to your error steps is a string while range(steps) means that steps must be an integer cause range iterates over an integer n ( from 0 to n-1). Check if steps integer or not using `print(type(steps))` if it  is a string  try using this `steps = int(steps)` it will type convert it to integer. If there is an character in steps it will return another error `can convert str to string`.  If that occours trace every occourance of steps and check where steps(int) is converted to str using `print(type(steps))`

```
    class SearchCell(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, steps, multiplier, prev_prev_C, prev_C, curr_C, reduction, prev_reduction):
    super(SearchCell, self).__init__()
    self.steps = int(steps)     # change here
    self.multiplier = multiplier
    self.reduction = reduction
  
    if prev_reduction:
      self.prep0 = FactorizedReduce(prev_prev_C,curr_C, affine=False)
    else:
      self.prep0 = ReLUConvBN(prev_prev_C, curr_C, 1, 1, 0, affine=False)
    self.prep1 = ReLUConvBN(prev_C, curr_C, 1, 1, 0, affine=False)

    self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
    for i in range(int(steps)):  change here
        for j in range(2+i):
            stride = 2 if reduction and j < 2 else 1
            op = MixedOp(curr_C, stride)
            self.layers.append(op)

  def forward(self, s0, s1, weights):
    s0 = self.prep0(s0)
    s1 = self.prep1(s1)
    states = [s0, s1]
    offset = 0
    for i in range(int(self.steps)):  #change here
      s = sum([self.layers[offset + j](h, weights[offset + j]) for j, h in enumerate(states)])
      offset += len(states)
      states.append(s)

    return torch.cat(states[-self.multiplier:], dim=1)
```

I have edited the code again check if this works or not. I `type converted stpes` everywhere cause i can run the code myself and tell  where the typeconverion of `steps` is happening so i used int(steps) where ever `steps` is used. And check my comment below as well

Comment: I tried it, it still gives an error
type(steps) is string.

Comment: How can I contact you?

Comment: How can I contact Naman and  Christoph Rackwitz ?

Comment: if it still gives an error check weather when you called the function ;  did u passed the parameter steps?? if yes check during the function call steps was `string` or `int` if its string then convert it if int only give us more info. And about contact detail u can ask questions here we all are here to help.